# Converting VC++ 6.0 to VC++ 2005

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have converted a C++ program written for VC++ 6.0 to VC++ 2005 with Visual Studio 2005.

This raises a lot of errors because VC++ 2005 is somehow more "strict" than 6.0.

There are two possible solutions I can think of, but I don't know if it is possible.

Is it possible to change the level of "strictness" in VS2005, so the application can be compiled with VC++ 2005?

When developing a .NET-application it is possible to change the .NET-framework version for a specific application. Is this possible in for VC++ (Switching from 2005 to 6.0 after I have upgraded the solution)?

I am new to VC++, so I'm "Learning while Programming".

Comment: It's better to keep separate versions of your project.  One for 6, one for 2005.  I'd also recommend to skip 2005 and go to 2010.  To answer one your questions, I don't think you can revert back to 6 once you've converted your project to 2005.

Comment: VC++ 6 is known for being an awful and buggy compiler. The sooner you move away from it and fix all the "new" issues, the better

Comment: How did .NET get thrown in here? VC++ 6.0 does not have any support for .NET. It has never even heard of it. If you're migrating to a newer version of Visual Studio, there's no reason for you to toss .NET into the mix. All of the later versions of Visual C++ support native compilation (meaning native C++ code without any .NET stuff). That's what I'd recommend you stick with if you're trying to learn C++ programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2005 does not let you "compile as" an older compiler version.  VS 2012 allows you to compile as VS 2010, but that is the first time VS has had such a feature.

If you want to upgrade a project to VS 2005, you will have to just bite the bullet and fix the problems.  **But that's a good thing!**  In my experience the "stricter" compiler really has pointed bugs in the original code.

While you're going through the pain of upgrading your compiler, you should jump to the latest (VS 2012) if that's an option.

---

Aside:  In .NET you are *targeting* a particular .NET version, because the end user may have a different .NET version installed on their computer.  But with C++, you are "targeting" x86 or x64, not a particular compiler.

Comment: Almost right. VS 2010 actually was the first version to introduce [support for multi-targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx), assuming that you had the desired version(s) of the compiler installed. Of course, I agree with the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a feeling that this would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The very first time when you will open the project written in Visual studio 6.0 into Visual studio 2005 the IDE will convert the project and report the errors.

It will list down all the errors and warnings in the conversion report and display it to you.

You won't be able to successfully build your project until unless you remove all these errors. However, you can change the setting to bend this rule so that only selected list of errors can be displayed.

Follow the below steps to do so :
1) Open the visual studio 6.0 project in Visual studio 2005 project.
2) Go to Tools menu item in Visual studio menu.
3) Go to Options Menu item.
4) Go to Performance Tools.
5) Go to Rules.
you will find the list of all the errors/warning and how they need to be reported. You may change the actions as per your convenience.

I hope this information will be useful to you.